# ImportError: No module named amazonaws

Tags: java, aws-sdk, jython, jython-2.7

Following is my code:-

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/jython_2_7-lib/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.920.jar")


from com.amazonaws import *
from com.amazonaws.auth import InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider
from com.amazonaws.regions import Regions
from com.amazonaws.services.s3 import *
from com.amazonaws.services.s3.model import DeleteObjectRequest
```

I verified that path is getting added to the sys.path by printing sys.path, I have checked couple of articles but did not help. I tried appending both jar's absolute path and just till lib directory as well.

using following jars from amazon aws sdk and version is 1.11.920:-

```
aws-java-sdk 
aws-java-sdk-s3
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to import aws-java-sdk-core-.jar as well.

The core jar provides all the basic classes for the s3 or auth jars.